# Mobile Programming Advice

Tags: java, android, c++, ide, project

I'm 17 years old. I'm a student at high-school.

I want to learn to program on Android and start making useful apps - I have some ideas I could implement, they're basic, but ingenious. The thing is I don't know where to start.

I know that to be able to program on Android, you have to understand Java. My only interaction with Java was about a year ago, when I had to make a bridge between 2 programs. I did it by imitating other's codes. So basically, I'm a newbie regarding Java.

This is my know-how:

1. C++ is my main language in which I program: I program around 4 hours a day. I make extensive use of OOP concepts, which is a very significant trait of C++. I've started programming C++ around 4-5 years ago.
2. I did a couple of projects, which involved micro-controllers.
3. I don't know if it helps, but I'm very good at building technical things in reality.

The question is: can somebody help me find a good way to learn to program in Android environment? Maybe someone who was in the same situation as mine. I'd prefer using only resources found on internet.

PS: The thing is, there's a contest in March about mobile applications, and I'd like to go there to learn something. First of all, I must have a project finished, so I can go there. Without this, I can't.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html. By the way your question appears to be off-topic. Try to google android tutorials, I think you'll find what you need.

Comment: I would shoot for going next March

Comment: You think that one month is not enough, right? Is Java harder to learn than to learn the Android API?

Comment: Depending on what you want to build but with no Java experience, yes, I think it is not enough. To your second question, probably because its a whole language not a framework

Comment: I built my first 3 "apps" in a week with a basic knowledge of Java. But they were simple (display a name, display something when clicking a button, and a simple calculator) so it depends on what you need to build and how quickly you can learn basic Java/

Comment: It's quite basic, or this is what I think: I have to pair 2 bluetooth devices and make a nice interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start reading and following

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html?utm_content=bufferf56e9&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=google&utm_campaign=Buffer

Secondly you can download and study some good books on Android Development after going through some basic apps.

**Professional Android 4 Application Development: Edition 3** by **Reto Meier** is a very good book.

Finally start active participation in Android forums, Webinars and specially don't forget to test your apps on different Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best reference to starting with Android?

Start in [Android](http://developer.android.com) Developer website and get to know the basic API. You can also search in Youtube is a good source of hundreds if not thousands of tutorials relate to Android SDK.

> What is the best IDE to developing Android and testing the Android
>   softwares?

You can use either Eclipse, a great IDE for java/android SDK, or the new [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) provided by google which I think is promising.

Beside the slow emulator provided by the SDK there is a good alternative and is [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Get Started Today -> [SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) & [First Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z149x12sXsw)

Wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Java, you should start with [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

After that, you are ready for the [Android Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Android also provides an IDE for developing apps, just in case the question will arise.

Good luck!